# SQLAlchemy complex relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have two (network)tables: interfaces and connections (below), where connections connect two interfaces.
I would like to create a relation in interfaces, which will allow me to get the connected interface of some interface, but don't know how to create this relation in the interfaces class?

would it be something like `neighbour = relationship('Interface', primaryjoin='???')` in the Interfaces class?
I guess I cannot get past that Interface.id would be present twice in the criteria string - once for 'this' interface referring to connections.a or .b, and then subsequently either .b or .a referring back to the 'other' interface?

```
class Interface(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_interface'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('un_interface', 'name', unique=True),
    )

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)    

class Connection(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_connection'
    __table_args__ = (
    Index('un_connection', 'a', 'b', unique=True),
    )
    a = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tbl_interface.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    b = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tbl_interface.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),     primary_key=True)
    intf_a = relationship('Interface', primaryjoin='Connection.a == Interface.id')
    intf_b = relationship('Interface', primaryjoin='Connection.b == Interface.id')
```

EDIT: 
I have this working:

```
tbl_connection = Table('tbl_connection', Base.metadata,
    Column('a', Integer, ForeignKey('tbl_interface.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True),
    Column('b', Integer, ForeignKey('tbl_interface.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True),
    CheckConstraint('a > b', name='a_over_b')
    )


class Interface(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbl_interface'
    __table_args__ = (
        Index('un_interface''name', unique=True),
    )

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)
    neighbor_interface = relationship('Interface', uselist=False,
                               secondary=tbl_connection,
                               primaryjoin=id == tbl_connection.c.a,
                               secondaryjoin=id == tbl_connection.c.b,
                               backref='whatever_questionmark'
                               )
```

I specifically needed the `uselist=False`, as otherwise I'd get this error: `TypeError: Incompatible collection type: Interface is not list-like` when inserting connection records.
I found that in [One to one self relationship in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872873/one-to-one-self-relationship-in-sqlalchemy)

This allows me to do the below, which is really cool :)

```
    inta = Interface(name='inta')
    intb = Interface(name='intb')
    inta.neighbor_interface = intb
    ses.add(inta)
    ses.add(intb)
    ses.commit()
    inta_copy = ses.query(Interface).filter(Interface.name == 'inta').first()
    intb_copy = ses.query(Interface).filter(Interface.name == 'intb').first()
    print('a:{}, b:{}'.format(intfa.neighbor_interface.name, intfb.neighbor_interface.name))
```

However, this doesn't help me, since only one if the two interfaces will correctly be able to fetch their opposite neighbor.

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship. If you decide to use `Connection` as the secondary as well, read the warning in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object.

Comment: Thanks - I think that does it - won't you drop an answer?

Comment: Are the connections btw. bidirectional, or unidirectional?

Comment: bi-directional..?

Comment: @IljaEverilä: won't you drop a response so I can accept it?